# LNK2019 and LNK2001 when using quickfix library in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, quickfix

I'm building a project using Qt Creator, which at the same time, using QuickFIX library. When I try to build the project using MSVC 2015 32bits build, it always has these two kinds of linker error:

> error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: static double __cdecl FIX::DoubleConvertor::fast_strtod(char const *,int,int *)" (?fast_strtod@DoubleConvertor@FIX@@CANPBDHPAH@Z) referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl FIX::DoubleConvertor::convert(class 
>   std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,double &)" (?convert@DoubleConvertor@FIX@@SA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AAN@Z)
>
> error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static double         __cdecl FIX::DoubleConvertor::fast_strtod(char const *,int,int *)" (?fast_strtod@DoubleConvertor@FIX@@CANPBDHPAH@Z

But I'm not using these double convertor anywhere in my project and I thought the quickfix library should have export all function from its source.

I've tried it on 64bits or MSVC 2017 build, nothing works..
I've been trying these for several weeks... It's driving me crazy

edit: my .pro file:

```
DEPENDPATH += $$(QuickFIX_VS2017)/include/quickfix
INCLUDEPATH += $$(QuickFIX_VS2017)/include/quickfix

Debug:LIBS += -L$$(QuickFIX_VS2017)/x64/Debug/ -lquickfix
Debug:PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$(QuickFIX_VS2017)/x64/Debug/quickfix.lib

Release:LIBS += -L$$(QuickFIX_VS2017)/x64/Release -lquickfix
Release:PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$(QuickFIX_VS2017)/x64/Release/quickfix.lib
```

Comment: show your .pro....

Comment: Where are the header and source files in your .pro file? Show us. and this error should link to some .obj file. What is the name of the object file?